# web crawling from BBC website using XPath

Tags: java, dom, xpath, web-crawler

This is an example of a typical webpage I am trying to crawl

http://www.bbc.com/news/business-31013604

If you inspect the element of the webpage. The main article is under

```
<div class="story-body">
```

However, when I try to get the main content using

```
         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("nutch");
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("crawl_data");
        BasicDBObject bo = new BasicDBObject("url", url).append("fetch_time", new Date());

        bo.append("article_text", getXPathValue(doc,"//DIV[@class='story-body']"));
```

I am not able to get the article content. In the database, it shows null in that field.

I have successfully crawled some pages from reuters, so fucntion getXPathValue should be correct.

I fetch pages using http request. Don't know if that is the issue here.

Comment: Please show your code, and tag the question with the correct programming language.

Comment: Try `//DIV[@class='story-body']/p/text()` to get the content of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are crawling an XHTML page (or at least a document in the XHTML namespace). The most significant difference between HTML and XHTML is that XHTML documents have a *default* namespace:

```
<root xmlns="www.example-of-default-namespace.com"/>
```

An XPath expression that does not take into account namespaces, for example

```
//root
```

will never find this element, because it's in a namespace.

---

The same happens with your XHTML document. There are two ways to solve this problem.

**Register the XHTML namespace**

The first, and more appropriate, solution is to *register* or *declare* the XHTML namespace in your code, and then use a prefix in your XPath expression. Since you do not show any code, I can hardly comment on that, we don't even know the programming language.

**Ignore namespaces**

Secondly, you can ignore any namespaces by modifying your XPath expression to

```
//*[local-name() = 'div' and @class='story-body']
```

Here `*` is a wildcard for any element, in any (or no) namespace, and `local-name()` returns the local part of an element or attribute name. In XML, there are *qualified names* that look like:

```
prefix:root
```

The first part of this qualified name is the *prefix*, and the second part is the *local name* of this element. So, the result of `local-name(prefix:root)` is `root`.

Also note that I have lowercased "div". HTML might be case-insensitive, but XHTML, and by extension, XML, and by extension, XPath are not.

Comment: I am using nutch to do the web crawling. so I am using java for the development of the nutch plugin as well.  pls enlighten me on the 1st solution. Also for your second solution, what is the meaning of local-name? and also the meaning of "*". Thank you!

Comment: @hao You absolutely have to share your code, and retag the question. But before that, please try the second solution and let me know if it works. I'll edit my answer and explain it a bit more.

Comment: Thank you I have added in the java  code for your reference

Comment: @hao Other possible problems are: What you are looking for is generated by javascript, or the content is not really in that div. Try `//*[local-name() = 'div' and @class='story-body']//*[local-name() = 'p']`.

Comment: sorry  it does not work. but thank you for your effort!